# Reference request for the analysis of a nonlinear Fokker-Planck type PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, initial-value-problems, parabolic-pde

It is well-known that the linear Fokker-Planck equation (written in one space dimension for simplicity) $$\partial_t \rho = \partial_x \left(\rho_\infty \partial_x\left(\frac{\rho}{\rho_\infty}\right)\right) \label{1}\tag{1}$$ where $\rho_\infty$ (say for instance of the form $\rho_\infty(x) \propto \mathrm{e}^{-V(x)}$ for some smooth and convex potential $V(x)$ growing sufficiently fast at infinity) is the unique equilibrium distribution to which the solution of (\ref{1}) converges, admits a family of Lyapunov functionals of the form (where $\phi$ is some convex function fulfilling certain properties) $$\mathrm{H}_\phi[\rho] = \int_{\mathbb R} \phi\left(\frac{\rho}{\rho_\infty}\right) \rho_\infty \,\mathrm{d} x \label{2}\tag{2}$$ for the study of the convergence to equilibrium problem, see for instance [this monograph](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-34219-1). However, I am wondering if there are references for investigation/study of the large-time convergence behavior of the following nonlinear Fokker-Planck type equation
$$\partial_t \rho = \partial_x \left(\mathcal{F}[\rho]\, \partial_x\left(\frac{\rho}{\mathcal{F}[\rho]}\right)\right) \label{3}\tag{3}$$ where $\mathcal{F} \colon \rho \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb R) \to \mathcal{F}[\rho] \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb R)$ is a sort of "quasi-stationary distribution" for the PDE (\ref{3}) with $\mathcal{F}[\rho_\infty] = \rho_\infty$. Here quasi-stationarity rough means (loosely speaking) that $\mathcal{F}[\rho]$ "takes the same form" as the true equilibrium $\rho_\infty$ (for example, they are both Gaussian but with different variance or they are both exponential distributions with different mean values). I am wondering if  there some recent or classical reference for the investigation of the large time behavior of such type of nonlinear Fokker-Planck equation, especially the construction of Lyapunov functionals. I have to admit that my question is a not very clear as the analysis of (\ref{3}) will depend on the specific choice of the map/nonlinearity $\mathcal{F}[\cdot]$, but I am hoping that some references pointing to analysis of Fokker-Planck type equations with the very specific structure as indicated in (\ref{3}) can be found.